# RedirectToAction fails to show the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 controllers A and B, both of which have their "index.cshtml". I make an ajax call into a method of A which in turn calls *RedirectToAction* to a method of B.
But the "index" view of B doesn't show up even though the ajax call succeeds.
Ajax

```
@.ajax(function()
 {
   ...
   url:"A/MethodToRedirect",
   ...
 });
Controller A
{
   public IActionResult MethodToRedirect(param)
   {
       // do something
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "B");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect this way using ajax. There are two ways :

1. You use a partial view

```
return PartialView("Index");
```

and add to your ajax:

```
  success: function (result) {
                    $(div).html(result); // div -id of your div outside of partial
}
```

2. Use full url

```
return Redirect("http://www.myapp.com");
```

or return javascript

```
    return Content("<script>window.location = 'http://www.myapp.com';</script>");
```